# Python selenium browser driver.back()

Tags: python, selenium

I have created a little screen scraper and everything seems to be working great, the information is being pulled and saved in a db. The only problem I am having is sometimes Python doesn't use the `driver.back()` so it then trys to get the information on the wrong page and crashes. I have tried adding a `time.sleep(5)` but sometimes it still isn't working. I am trying to optimise it to take as little time as possible. So making it sleep for 30 seconds doesn't seem to be a good solution.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

This is the best solution. The `back()` and `forward()` methods aren't guaranteed to work.

```
driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

The JavaScript passed in accesses the pages DOM to navigate to the previous URL. I hope that this solves your problem.

Comment: Could we have a source for why selenium back/forward is not guaranteed to work? I am confident I could trust your answer based on the upvote, but additional specifics would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

Try relocating elements each time it goes back to previous page. That will surely work but it is time consuming.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).