# Always got TimeoutException error when using explicit wait in Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

I have the code below.

```
from selenium import  webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome() #
driver.implicitly_wait(10) #https://blog.csdn.net/u010895119/article/details/77005886
driver.get('http://www.aim.env.uea.ac.uk/aim/model4/model4d.php') #
button = driver.find_element_by_id('add_organic')#
button.click()#
input = driver.find_element_by_id("selection_box_id")#
input.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="selection_box_id"]/option[3]').click() #
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="selection_box_div"]/p/input').click()#
input = driver.find_element_by_id("selection_box_id")#
input.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="selection_box_id"]/option[7]').click()#
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="selection_box_div"]/p/input').click()# 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BacktoCalculation_id"]').click() #
#driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)") #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626783/python-selenium-browser-driver-back

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) # 
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainForm"]/div[2]/table/tbody/|tr/td[3]/input')))# 
element.click()
```

I always got timeout error as:

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

But when I try to directly find the element, it actually works. But I need to have an explicit wait here to make it safe. Can anyone help to find out the problem in the code above? Thanks a lot!

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainForm"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/input')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have a typo in your xpath

```
'//*[@id="mainForm"]/div[2]/table/tbody/|tr/td[3]/input' # error
'//*[@id="mainForm"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/input'  # ok
```

This works fine

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) #
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainForm"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/input')))#
element.click()
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot. I spent so much time on it but could not find it out...